# How to read values from one column in dataframe depending on the value from adjacent column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data frame that has User names and amounts I need to pick only values where username is in Upper Case and does not have hyphen "-" in amount

```
userid  username  amount
0   MAX   1.00
1   will   -
2   JOHN   5.22
3   sara   -
4   Nell  1.121
```

I need output dataframe as

```
MAX     1.00
JOHN    5.22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use is.upper() to check if the 'username' column is uppercase:

```
df[df.username.str.isupper()]
```

And your amount should not be the string '-' which would be the following:

```
df[df.amount!='-']
```

Combined would be:

```
df.loc[(df.amount!='-')&(df.username.str.isupper())]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html) for test only uppercases strings with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for test not equal, chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['username'].str.isupper() & df['amount'].ne('-')]
```

Or:

```
df = df[df['username'].str.contains('^[A-Z]+$') & df['amount'].ne('-')]
print (df)
   userid username amount
0       0      MAX   1.00
2       2     JOHN   5.22
```